# Using string formatting in an input prompt?

Tags: python, string

I'm sure it's easy to see what I'm trying to do here. Am I completely wrong or making a simple mistake? I want it to say:

> 'PlayerA's name', Please choose..

```
playerA = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
playerB = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
choiceA = input("%s, Please choose; Rock (R), Paper (P), or Scissors (S): ") % (playerA)
choiceB = input("%s, Please choose; Rock, Paper, or Scissors: ") % (playerB)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your substitution needs to be done entirely within the parentheses:

```
raw_input("%s, Please choose; Rock (R), Paper (P), or Scissors (S): " % (playerA))
```

otherwise it will be done on the *result* of the call.

Also there doesn't seem to be a reason for you to use raw_input sometimes and input other times. If you're on Python 2, use raw_input *always*.

Comment: Thanks for this. Doing this as part of a college assignment and lecturer sais to specifically use input for the choice. But thanks I'll change it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are your parantheses. Try it like this:

```
playerA = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
playerB = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
choiceA = input("%s, Please choose; Rock (R), Paper (P), or Scissors (S): " % (playerA))
choiceB = input("%s, Please choose; Rock, Paper, or Scissors: " % (playerB))
```